# ImageView and textfields in a single line using Eureka framework

Tags: ios, iphone, frameworks, eureka-forms

I'm currently using Eureka framework. I want my form to have a ImageView on the left side, and textfields or labels on the right side, similar as shown in the picture. Any ideas of what I need to do to accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: You could to create a subclass cell and row in Eureka, create a xib for the cell, and then the easiest way to create this layout in xib would be using a stack view

Comment: @LoganHenderson Could you give me an example? I can't find much information related to Eureca on internet, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is taken directly from the Eureka README

```
// Custom Cell with value type: Bool
// The cell is defined using a .xib, so we can set outlets :)
public class CustomCell: Cell<Bool>, CellType {
    @IBOutlet weak var switchControl: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    public override func setup() {
        super.setup()
        switchControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CustomCell.switchValueChanged), for: .valueChanged)
    }

    func switchValueChanged(){
        row.value = switchControl.on
        row.updateCell() // Re-draws the cell which calls 'update' bellow
    }

    public override func update() {
        super.update()
        backgroundColor = (row.value ?? false) ? .white : .black
    }
}

// The custom Row also has the cell: CustomCell and its correspond value
public final class CustomRow: Row<CustomCell>, RowType {
    required public init(tag: String?) {
        super.init(tag: tag)
        // We set the cellProvider to load the .xib corresponding to our cell
        cellProvider = CellProvider<CustomCell>(nibName: "CustomCell")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that it's what I've been looking for!